# how to Add a DefaultEndpoint if No endpoint mapping is found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-ws

In my Spring boot app replacing a legacy, i have defined a webservice EndPoint.
soem of the user today comes in with payload that does nothave the namespace URI. 
since namespace is not there, Spring throws  No Endpoint mapping found error.

Is there a way i can add a default Endpoint so that it will get invoked if no mapping is found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to create a fallback method for all request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFallback() {
    return "Fallback for GET Requests";
}
```

You can get more information here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping

Comment: Thank you Sujit in my case i am using spring-ws for soap, not rest controller. i was able to correct by adding a new method with no namespace in the @PayloadRoot for handling requests coming in without a namespace.

Comment: That's great Anil

Comment: @Anil how did you manage to make the endpoint process your message. Were you missing just he namespace or also your body of SOAP xml was empty?

Comment: @Dusko, In my case adding a new method with blank namespace helped to resolve the issue.@PayloadRoot(namespace = "", localPart = "yourlocalpart")

Comment: @Anil ok, for me the problem is that I have no namespace or local part, and then I can't really fall back to anything. Thanks though for the comment :)